# WPML: wp_query() returns posts in all languages rather than just current one

Tags: wordpress, wpml

No matter whether I use it from my page in French version or in English version, wp_query() returns my custom post types in all languages, not just in the current one. Get_posts() does the same thing too.

When I visit my page in French, I want them to return CPTs in the current language only. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using **get_posts()**, set **suppress_filters** to **false**:

```
$myPosts = get_posts(array(
    'suppress_filters' => false
));
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts#Parameters

Comment: link updated: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Answer (score 5):

That's the best way I found to fetch posts on a specific language using WPML...

In my case I need to find a post by it's title on a specific language and return the ID of the post:

```
$lang='en';
$title='The title you are searching!';

    function getWpIdByTitle($title, $lang){
        global $sitepress;
        // WPML Super power language switcher...
        $sitepress->switch_lang( $lang );
        $args = array(
          'title'        => $title,
          'post_type'   => 'your-post-type', // Default: post
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'suppress_filters' => false,
          'numberposts' => 1
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        return $wp_query->post->ID;
    }
```

You may use the $wp_query->post as the result of the fetch and do the echo's of title, content, etc.

This way you don't need to use the

`do_action( 'wpml_set_element_language_details', $set_language_args );`

to connect your language posts, neither the

`icl_object_id(1,'post',false,ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);`

to get the ID of a post on a specific languange.

Comment: Top! Also, I would reset $sitepress->switch_lang() to the $current_language after use. I was using this inside a shortcode, ran the query, but then couldn't see any product because I forced the language change. Restoring the previous language made it work